# Producing a searchable portable static HTML site from Confluence XML or HTML

Tags: javascript, python, xml, static-site

I want to convert documentation from Confluence into a static HTML site. I want the html to be searchable and portable. People need to be able to use it on devices that are not connected to the internet. Ideally, the static html would be responsive as well.

This is what I've got so far:

1. I can export Confluence content into static HTML or XML.
2. I can post process the export with a static site generator tool.
3. I can use Bootstrap for making the final product look good and responsive.

My problem really is  really in point 2. I have started to read up on static site generator tools here: https://www.staticgen.com/. There are just too many of them.

My scripting skills are Python, basic Javascript, basic php. I would prefer to convert XML output into static html using Python.

Which of the many static site generator tools out there can handle complex and large XML (+100 MB)?

Would you recommend to do this in Python or is Javascript the better tool? (I really like [www.metalsmith.io](http://www.metalsmith.io)).

Should I aim for making this project fit into Bootstrap or is it less hazzle to create the entire template for the static page from scratch?

Comment: Have you considered using XSLT? Processors such as Saxon are designed to have a small XML footprint, regardless of the size of the input. I haven't had as large files as yours, but Saxon produced 1,101 HTML files from a 9.1 Mb input XML with *huge*, multiple, document spanning lookups, without breaking in a sweat.

Comment: I have not heard of XSLT before. I'll check it out! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Then you're in for a treat! XSLT is strongly declarative, rather than your current skill set of imperative languages and so it may take a while to get used to that mindset. But it's well worth the effort – if only *because* of the differences with the languages you already know.

Comment: I see :-). I've started reading up on it and really like what I see.

Comment: All right, so I've read up on XSLT and I think it's the right choice for the job. Thanks for pointing it out. So the work chain would be:

XML > XSLT > HTML

Can you recommend any static site builder that is based on XSLT?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try [Instant Websites for Confluence Cloud](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/instant-websites/cloud/overview).

It produces a static website on AWS based on Confluence content.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.